# Page level permissions requited in opencart admin

Tags: php, opencart, admin

i am using openCart version 2.3. In admin I have created two user groups (`administrator` and `staff`).

Group `staff` has restricted permissions. As name suggest this group will be assigned to the employees. They will be working on order page. However I want that on the order page, customer email and phone number should be hide from them. How can i achieve this?

I tried but could not get the admin user group type on the order page. If I am able to to get the group type on this page, I can hide these fields(`customer` `email` and `phone number`) on this order page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `$this->user->user_group_id` from page controller.

If you try to call this from view, you will not get value, because in OpenCart `$this` object is not completly passed to views.

Comment: thanks lucorp. on which page i would do this ? can you please share an idea. i am novice in opencart

Comment: You can find it in /admin/controller/sale/order.php in this file you should look for method edit()

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin -> controller -> sale -> open order.php in any text editor

find this line public function info () {

add this code inside it `$data['permission'] = $this->user->getId();`

and then go to admin > view > template > sale > order_info.tpl

```
<?php if ($permission == 1) { ?>
<?php echo $email; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Thats all